# Настройка поддоменов на Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, поддомены

У меня есть выделенный сервер и домен `example.com`. Я разработал три приложения и хочу к каждому приложению, запущенное на одном сервере на разных портах, дать свой поддомен: `public`, `admin` и по умолчанию

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
+----------+--------------------+------+-----------------+
| Поддомен |        URL         | Порт |   Приложение    |
+----------+--------------------+------+-----------------+
| admin    | admin.example.com  |   82 | SpringAppAdmin  |
| public   | public.example.com |   81 | SpringAppPublic |
| -        | example.com        |   80 | SpringAppMain   |
+----------+--------------------+------+-----------------+
```

Как в Spring Boot прописывать поддомен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему установкой Nginx на сервер.

Ресурсы, которые помогли:
[Развертывание приложения Spring Boot на NGINX](https://ikurek.pl/deploying-spring-boot-with-nginx/)

*Мой сервер работает на Ubuntu 18.04*

1. Устанавливаем Ngninx на сервер
2. в папке `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` создаем файл с вашим сайтом `example.com`:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # Измените назввние сервера
        server_name example.com;

        #Корень приложения в моем проекте - это /
        location /{
             # измените порт на ваш
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # Измените назввние сервера
        server_name admin.example.com;

        #Корень приложения в моем проекте - это /
        location /{
             # измените порт на ваш
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}
```

3. Прописываем "soft link":

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

4. Удаляем "soft link" на файл`default`, чтобы заменить его нашими настройками nginx:

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Answer (score 1):

Отредактируйте конфиг tomcat'a `server.xml`, добавьте хосты:

```
<Host name="admin.example.com" appBase="webapps/SpringAppAdmin" autoDeploy="true">
  <Alias>admin.example.com</Alias>
  <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/SpringAppAdmin"/>
</Host>

<Host name="public.example.com" appBase="webapps/SpringAppPublic" autoDeploy="true">
  <Alias>public.example.com</Alias>
  <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/SpringAppPublic"/>
</Host>

<Host name="example.com" appBase="webapps/SpringAppMain" autoDeploy="true">
  <Alias>example.com</Alias>
  <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/SpringAppMain"/>
</Host>
```

В данном случае хостам будет все равно на каких внутренних портах крутятся ваши приложения.

Единственное, не забудьте настроить DNS записи вашего домена.

Comment: Увы, данный момент не могу проверить на своем сервере, но посмотрев другие вопросы на SO, уверен, что у вас верное решение

Comment: @Antonio112009 если бы в условии фигурировал nginx, то дал бы вам еще вариант и с ним, но вы уже сами разобрались =)

Comment: Я на тот момент про NGINX еще не думал. Скажем так, я даже не знал как он работает. Я только вчера нашел вариант с NGINX и имплементировал его на сервер